# Is "stat" a cpu-consuming command?

Tags: java, linux, file, linux-kernel, filesystems

my question is : Does the "stat" command in Linux system consume too much CPU if I constantly call this command (e.g. 50 times per sec)?

This is how the question came from:

I am writing programs in Java where it frequently calls File.length() method. I noticed CPU usage reaches 20%(which is really high) very soon.

I checked the source code of File.length() and it led me to very deep level of file system where I see the source code goes like this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
...
#define stat64 stat
...
    // Android-changed: Name changed because of added thread policy check
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_getLength0(JNIEnv *env, jobject this,
                                       jobject file)
{
    jlong rv = 0;

    WITH_FIELD_PLATFORM_STRING(env, file, ids.path, path) {
        struct stat64 sb;
        if (stat64(path, &sb) == 0) {
            rv = sb.st_size;
        }
    } END_PLATFORM_STRING(env, path);
    return rv;
}
```

It looks like its using the "stat" command in the system.
I checked the man page of stat :

> These functions return information about a file. No permissions are required on the file itself, but-in the case of stat() and lstat() - execute (search) permission is required on all of the directories in path that lead to the file.

As it does not require read permission, I wonder if I can conclude that it does not open the file and read the content and thus should consume little CPU?

Where can I see the actual implementation of the comman "stat"?

Any thoughts will help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is “stat” a cpu-consuming command?

It is a syscall and not a command.  (If it was a command, it would be a lot more expensive.)

> As it does not require read permission, I wonder if I can conclude that it does not open the file and read the content and thus should consume little CPU?

It is not a valid conclusion.  You can only draw a tentative conclusion about `stat` CPU utilization if you have a deep knowledge of what it actually does, and how it does it.

In the case of `stat`, it is too complicated to predict from first principles.  Even if you have a deep understanding of how a modern Linux kernel works, there too may aspects to consider to make a reliable prediction.

To illustrate some of the potential complexity:

- resolving the path could involve doing lookups of directory entries in multiple directories
- access checks need to be performed for each directory lookup
- directories and inodes may need to be read from disk
- disk blocks and/or metadata could be cached
- loopback and remote file systems make things even more complicated

In some cases, this could be relatively fast.  In others, not.

In short ... no you should not assume that.

> Where can I see the actual implementation of `stat`.

Typically it is all in the Linux kernel source code.  But in some cases the code of things like user-space loopback filesystems might be involved.

There is a LOT to trawl through.  I wouldn't recommend it ... unless you have a strong desire to learn about kernel internals.

A better idea would be to write a benchmark in C / C++ and measure it.